# How to return headers of columns that match a criteria for every row in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe **df** of the form :

```
     Col1      Col2      Col3      Col4

0    True      False     True      False
1    False     False     False     False
2    False     True      False     False
3    True      True      True      True
```

Here True and False are boolean values.

I am trying to generate a new pandas dataframe **new_df** which should look like:

```
     Matched_Cols

0    [Col1, Col3]
1    []
2    [Col2]
3    [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4]
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's with array-data processing -

```
def iter_accum(df):
    c = df.columns.values.astype(str)
    return pd.DataFrame({'Matched_Cols':[c[i] for i in df.values]})
```

Sample output -

```
In [41]: df
Out[41]: 
    Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
0   True  False   True  False
1  False  False  False  False
2  False   True  False  False
3   True   True   True   True

In [42]: iter_accum(df)
Out[42]: 
               Matched_Cols
0              [Col1, Col3]
1                        []
2                    [Col2]
3  [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4]
```

**Approach #2**

Another with slicing on array-data and some boolean-indexing -

```
def slice_accum(df):
    c = df.columns.values.astype(str)
    a = df.values
    vals = np.broadcast_to(c,a.shape)[a]
    I = np.r_[0,a.sum(1).cumsum()]
    ac = []
    for (i,j) in zip(I[:-1],I[1:]):
        ac.append(vals[i:j])
    return pd.DataFrame({'Matched_Cols':ac})
```

#### Benchmarking

Other proposed solution(s) -

```
# @jezrael's soln-1
def jez1(df):
    return df.apply(lambda x: x.index[x].tolist(), axis=1)

# @jezrael's soln-2
def jez2(df):
    return df.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').str.split(',')

# @Shubham Sharma's soln
def Shubham1(df):
    return df.agg(lambda s: s.index[s].values, axis=1) 

# @sammywemmy's soln
def sammywemmy1(df):
    return pd.DataFrame({'Matched_Cols':[np.compress(x,y) for x,y in zip(df.to_numpy(),np.tile(df.columns,(len(df),1)))]})
```

Using [`benchit`](https://github.com/droyed/benchit) package (few benchmarking tools packaged together; disclaimer: I am its author) to benchmark proposed solutions.

```
import benchit
funcs = [iter_accum,slice_accum,jez1,jez2,Shubham1,sammywemmy1]
in_ = {n:pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(n,n)>0.5, columns=['Col'+str(i) for i in range(1,n+1)]) for n in [4,20,100,200,500,1000]}
t = benchit.timings(funcs, in_, input_name='Len')
t.rank()
t.plot(logx=True)
```

[image]

Comment: jez1, jez2, subham1 return `Series` object but iter_accum, slice_accum and sammywemmy1 return `DataFrame`. Making all of them `Series` and benchmarking might be better. In that case, your's and sammy's might flatten a little. As DataFrame store column attribute while Series dont.

Comment: @Ch3steR Yeah converting to series for `iter_accum, slice_accum and sammywemmy1` would make them better. They are top3 anyway and would follow the same trend shape. So, I guess it's okay from a perspective of picking better ones. I was going more from OP's requirement as it stated it required a dataframe as output and didn't want to add additional code for the rest of the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter for each row index values, what are columns names in original `DataFrame` and then convert to lists:

```
df['Matched_Cols'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.index[x].tolist(), axis=1)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for matrix multiplication with columns names with separator, removed last separator value by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) and last use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['Matched_Cols'] = df.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').str.split(',')
```

---

```
print (df)
    Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4              Matched_Cols
0   True  False   True  False              [Col1, Col3]
1  False  False  False  False                        []
2  False   True  False  False                    [Col2]
3   True   True   True   True  [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unnecessarily long:

```
df['Matched_Col'] = [np.compress(x,y) for x,y in zip(df.to_numpy(),np.tile(df.columns,(len(df),1)))]

Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Matched_Col
0   True    False   True    False   [Col1, Col3]
1   False   False   False   False   []
2   False   True    False   False   [Col2]
3   True    True    True    True    [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['Matched_Cols'] = df.agg(lambda s: s.index[s].values, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4               Matched_Cols

0   True  False   True  False              [Col1, Col3]
1  False  False  False  False                        []
2  False   True  False  False                    [Col2]
3   True   True   True   True  [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4]
```