# Update another column based on logical operations on multiple columns pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logical-operators

I have a pandas dataframe as below. I want to logically check multiple columns `(A,B,C)` and update column D with OR operation and update the column names which has true by comma separating in column E. I am not sure on how to achieve it. Any leads will be helpful.

```
A     B     C      D     E
True  True  True   True  A,B,C
True  False True   True  A,C
False False False  False NA
False False True   True  C
```

Edit :

```
cols = ['A','B','C']
df['D'] = np.where(df[cols].eq(True).any(1), True, False)
```

I am able to come up with column D but not sure how to proceed with Column E

Comment: What did you try so far? (Code please)

Comment: I have edited the post with my code so far

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return headers of columns that match a criteria for every row in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62127534/how-to-return-headers-of-columns-that-match-a-criteria-for-every-row-in-a-pandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) + [`Series.str.rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) and [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
cols = pd.Index(['A', 'B', 'C'])
df['E'] = df[cols].dot(cols + ',').str.rstrip(',').replace('', np.nan)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

       A      B      C      D      E
0   True   True   True   True  A,B,C
1   True  False   True   True    A,C
2  False  False  False  False    NaN
3  False  False   True   True      C
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to use `stack`

```
s = df[cols].stack()

df['F'] = s[s.eq(True)].reset_index(1).groupby(level=0)['level_1'].agg(','.join)

print(df)

       A      B      C      D      E      F
0   True   True   True   True  A,B,C  A,B,C
1   True  False   True   True    A,C    A,C
2  False  False  False  False    NaN    NaN
3  False  False   True   True      C      C
```

Comment: I will try this as well. Thank you very much :)