# How to generate array column with values from other columns using Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am trying to convert some Pandas code to Dask.

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
   ListView_Lead_MyUnreadLeads  ListView_Lead_ViewCustom2 
0                            1                          1   
1                            1                          0   
2                            1                          1   
3                            1                          1   
4                            1                          1
```

In Pandas, I can use create a `Lists` column which includes the `List` if the row value is `1` like so:

```py
df['Lists'] = df.dot(df.columns+",").str.rstrip(",").str.split(",")
```

So the `Lists` column looks like:

```
                                               Lists
0  [ListView_Lead_MyUnreadLeads, ListView_Lead_Vi...
1                      [ListView_Lead_MyUnreadLeads]
2  [ListView_Lead_MyUnreadLeads, ListView_Lead_Vi...
3  [ListView_Lead_MyUnreadLeads, ListView_Lead_Vi...
4  [ListView_Lead_MyUnreadLeads, ListView_Lead_Vi...
```

In Dask, the `dot` function doesn't seem to work the same way. How can I get the same behavior / output?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Related question in Pandas: [How to return headers of columns that match a criteria for every row in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62127534/how-to-return-headers-of-columns-that-match-a-criteria-for-every-row-in-a-pandas)

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Going from boolean arrays to an object array containing lists of strings will likely blow up your memory and you throw away a lot of the features of dask.dataframe, which isn't designed to work with arrays of lists. Can you restructure your downstream workflow to work with the boolean arrays directly?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado – Yes, I need to eventually convert the final output to JSON which will need Lists formatted as a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some alternative ways to do it in Pandas.  You can try whether it works equally well in Dask.

```
cols = df.columns.values
df['Lists'] = [list(cols[x]) for x in df.eq(1).values]
```

or try:

```
df['Lists'] = df.eq(1).apply(lambda x: list(x.index[x]), axis=1)
```

The first solution using list comprehension provides better performance if your dataset is large.

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   ListView_Lead_MyUnreadLeads  ListView_Lead_ViewCustom2                                                     Lists
0                            1                          1  [ListView_Lead_MyUnreadLeads, ListView_Lead_ViewCustom2]
1                            1                          0                             [ListView_Lead_MyUnreadLeads]
2                            1                          1  [ListView_Lead_MyUnreadLeads, ListView_Lead_ViewCustom2]
3                            1                          1  [ListView_Lead_MyUnreadLeads, ListView_Lead_ViewCustom2]
4                            1                          1  [ListView_Lead_MyUnreadLeads, ListView_Lead_ViewCustom2]
```

Comment: I don't think Dask has `to_numpy` function

Comment: @HassanSyyid  If it has something like `tolist()` or `to_list()` should also work.  Sorry, I'm not familiar with Dask.  Just try to provide alternative solutions in Pandas and see whether you can do it in Dask.

Comment: Your second option works perfectly :)

Comment: @HassanSyyid  I seen from [this doc](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-creation.html#from-dask-dataframe) that the `.values` attribute is also supported from Dask.  If true, you can replace the `.to_numpy` function above by `.values` for first option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Dask version with `map_partitions`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ListView_Lead_MyUnreadLeads': [1,1,1,1,1], 'ListView_Lead_ViewCustom2': [1,0,1,1,1] })

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

def myfunc(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['Lists'] = df.dot(df.columns+",").str.rstrip(",").str.split(",")
    return df

ddf.map_partitions(myfunc).compute()
```

Comment: Is there a performance benefit to using `map_partitions` over `apply`?

Comment: Depends on the size of the data, but generally yes, https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions.html